# Cant connect to SQLite after deploying asp.net core (Blazor-server) on Ubuntu VM

Tags: .net, sqlite, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

The website is working perfect deploying it on azure web app(Linux) with signalR

I'm trying to deploye it on Linux (ubuntu 18.04). Every thing is woking fine.

The Problem is that the website cant connet to the sqlite database. (Only pages that depend on the DB don't load)

[image: Connection String]

Comment: IMO it's not a good idea to store the db file in wwwroot folder. It can be accessed as a static file with "/Travel.db" uri.

Comment: I tried this option Then used the connctionString: "Data Source=./Travel.db" not working ! I always try it on the IIS Express to make sure that the configration is write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On linux the path relative to the running process location should start with "."

```
"ConnectionString": {
  "TravelContextConenction": "Data Source=./wwwroot/Travel.db"
}
```

Comment: I tried "TravelContextConenction": "Data Source=./wwwroot/Travel.db" Didn't work , I tried a lot of options . I don't know , there meight be somthing need to be installed on ubuntu server ?

Comment: No, but you need to have write access on the file or directory if you want to create the file.

Comment: Thank you so much <3 , I had to do it on the entire directory couse sqlite creats other files.

Comment: But This permission needs to be applied on public not in the group permissions or the owner permissions , Is there a security issues with that ? For it to work the Numeric value = 777

Comment: Well, if you can reduce the scope it's better. The process need to write in the db file and so have the write access